# Mini keyboard has no home/end keys; how to type them?

Tags: keyboard

Some months ago I needed a small keyboard and bought an [Okion KM229](http://www.okion.com/en-us/scripts/product_info.asp?pid=548) without noticing that it has no Home or End key. This makes it tricky to type as I'm so used to using these keys. I haven't yet figured out if there is a key combination that issues Home and End keystrokes. Does anyone have experience of these keyboards and know how to issue those keystrokes? The keyboard is used on a PC running Windows XP.

I have used the contact form on the Okion USA web site to ask this question but received no response.

Wikipedia suggests that [Home](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key) and [End](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_key) keystrokes are issued with Fn-Left and Fn-Right on some limited size keyboards. However, although this keyboard has a Fn key, using it with the left and right keys does not produce the Home and End actions.

Comment: Fn-Left and Fn-Right is fairly standard for Home/End.

Comment: In case you have Fn key but it doesn't do the job, try Alt+RightArrow or Alt+LeftArrow instead(Alt might be called Meta on some keyboards)

Answer (score 58):

On most small keyboards (including many notebook keyboards) <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>→ (right arrow)</kbd> will function as the <kbd>End</kbd> key.

Comment: My laptop ***has*** (Home) and (End) keys, and yet (Fn)+(← (left arrow)) and (Fn)+(→ (right arrow)) function as Home and End.

Comment: Worked for me, not sure why anyone down voted it, as it doesn't require any external hotkey app (if it works on yours, that is)

Comment: Works for my laptop.  It's not marked like the other `Fn` keys... weird.

Comment: On mine they are marked. Now what about "Insert"? (Edit: It's Fn-PrtSc and marked as well.)

Comment: wt... I've been using my mini keyboard for almost 6 months now and I just realized this now.

Comment: Been using for allmost 6 months on screen keyboard for those keys, after I did that search lol.... Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks. This indeed does the trick for my Logitech MX Keys Mini. There are no visual cues for this, but it does work.

Answer (score 12):

Your best shot, in lieu of finding out if your keyboard has a proper key combo for this, is probably to use a program such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to assign a key combination as a hotkey for the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys.

For example the following would assign <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to the <kbd>Home</kbd> key and  <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to the <kbd>End</kbd> key.

```
#h::Home
#e::End
```

Simply install AutoHotkey, save those two lines to a file, `HomeEnd.ahk` for example, and run the newly created file, this should give you access to the Home and End keys via the hotkeys I mentioned.

Autohotkey also has a "compiler" that can convert a script into an executable by bundling the script and interpreter together so that you only have one thing to execute and don't need to install AutoHotkey on every machine.  You could simply have your compiled script on a USB key.

The [documentation for AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/) may also be of use to assign the keys to whatever key combo you like.

Comment: I'm familiar with AutoHotkey and will consider using it if I don't find any trick native to the keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem admittedly with a crappy Chinese imitation of an Apple mini keyboard (there literally is no model or manufacturer identifier on it whatsoever). I used AutoHotKey to map Win-x to End, and Win-z to Home. I had to do a bit more work to @Mokubai's answer in order to make Ctrl-End, Shift-End, and Ctrl-Shift-End work though:

```
;
; Home
;

; Win-z = Home = start of line
#z::Send {Home}

; Ctrl-Win-z = Ctrl-Home = start of document
^#z::Send {LCtrl down}{Home}{LCtrl up}

; Shift-Win-z = Shift-Home = select to start of line
+#z::Send {LShift down}{Home}{LShift up}

; Ctrl-Shift-Win-z = Ctrl-Shift-Home = select to start of document
^+#z::Send {LCtrl down}{LShift down}{Home}{LShift up}{LCtrl up}


;
; End
;

; Win-x = End = end of line
#x::Send {End}

; Ctrl-Win-x = Ctrl-End = end of document
^#x::Send {LCtrl down}{End}{LCtrl up}

; Shift-Win-x = Shift-End = select to end of line
+#x::Send {LShift down}{End}{LShift up}

; Ctrl-Shift-Win-x = Ctrl-Shift-End = select to start of document
^+#x::Send {LCtrl down}{LShift down}{End}{LShift up}{LCtrl up}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to bind  <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> ( right arrow ) for End and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> ( left arrow ) for Home keys. You can use following script

```
#Left::Send {Home}
#Right::Send {End}
```

**Solutions for Windows 10**
This is not relevant to the original question but like me, many users will reach here who are Windows 10 users too. There is a simple solution for them in the shape of [Microsoft PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases). You can remap any key combination with any other. So give it a try.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotkey is the simplest solution to this.  It took me a while to find the right mapping for my keyboard and I thought this was a good place to share it.  (Thank you *Ilan* for showing the CTRL and SHIFT combinations.)

My Dell Precision 7510 laptop does not have dedicated Home and End buttons but it does have dedicated PrtScr and Insert buttons ([like this](http://www.ultrabookreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/dell-7450-keyboard1.jpg)).  Because I normally use an external keyboard and I regularly use my Print Screen key I needed a way to toggle that button between being **Print Screen** and **Home** when using the laptop keyboard.  Building upon the example from *Iian*, I setup **Win+Print Screen** to *toggle* the override.

```
; My Dell Precision 7510 laptop does not have dedicated Home and End buttons 
; but it does have dedicated PrtScr and Insert buttons.  
; This script will override those buttons as Home and End.
; Idea from:  http://superuser.com/questions/412761/mini-keyboard-has-no-home-end-keys-how-to-type-them

; Use the Win+Printscreen key to toggle these hotkeys. They are only needed when using the laptop keyboard.
; Note that this script should be loaded after Snagit or other software that overrides the Print Screen key or those programs may fail to map properly.

#Printscreen::
T:=!T
if(T) ; If it's on
{
    ;--- Map the Printscreen and Insert keys ---
    Hotkey, Printscreen, Printscreen, On
    Hotkey, Insert, Insert, On
    SoundBeep 423, 100
    SoundBeep 423, 150
    ToolTip, Laptop PrtScr/Insert remapped to Home/End...
    Sleep, 1500
    ToolTip

    ;=== Home ===
    ; Note that MsgBox, ToolTip, and SoundBeep lines are not executing after the first key is mapped.  Hmm.  BS 7/27/2016
    ; Home = start of line
    Printscreen::Send {Home}

    ; Ctrl-Home = start of document
    ^Printscreen::Send {LCtrl down}{Home}{LCtrl up}

    ; Shift-Home = select to start of line
    +Printscreen::Send {LShift down}{Home}{LShift up}

    ; Ctrl-Shift-Home = select to start of document
    ^+Printscreen::Send {LCtrl down}{LShift down}{Home}{LShift up}{LCtrl up}

    ;=== End ===

    ; End = end of line
    Insert::Send {End}

    ; Ctrl-End = end of document
    ^Insert::Send {LCtrl down}{End}{LCtrl up}

    ; Shift-End = select to end of line
    +Insert::Send {LShift down}{End}{LShift up}

    ; Ctrl-Shift-End = select to start of document
    ^+Insert::Send {LCtrl down}{LShift down}{End}{LShift up}{LCtrl up}
}
else
{
    ;--- Disable the Printscreen and Insert key mapping ---
    Hotkey, Printscreen, Off
    Hotkey, Insert, Off
    SoundBeep 303, 150
    ToolTip, Laptop PrtScr/Insert remapping disabled...
    Sleep, 1500
    ToolTip
}
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the things you can try.

Fn+PgUp --->> Home

Fn+PgDn --->> End

or

Fn+RightArrow --->> Home

Fn+LeftArrow --->> End

Answer (score 1):

Using AutoHotkey why not Change the Caps Lock key to something useful like:

```
;Caps Lock Single Tap = End 
;Caps Lock Double Tap = Home

Capslock::
    KeyWait,Capslock
    KeyWait,Capslock,D T0.1
    If ErrorLevel
        Send {End}
    else
        Send {Home}
return
```

You can still use your caps lock key by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with many compact keyboards, because they lack dedicated “Home”’, “End”, “Page Up” and “Page Down” keys.

Doesn’t use of AutoHotKey open up some increased risks from hacking?

In any case the problem can easily be solved without use of AutoHotKey, by Windows users at least, using Microsoft PowerToys > Keyboard Manager > Shortcuts as mentioned above by Riz.

I use Win+left = Home, Win+right = End, Win+ up = Page Up, Win+down = Page Down. You can map any combination you like, but it is best to avoid use of the Ctrl key. The reason is that Powertoys does not offer StartofDoc or EndofDoc as “Mapped To” options but these are pre-installed in many programs, using the Ctrl key.

You do not need fancy Autotype scripts (or anything extra) for this. Just press and hold Ctrl, then use your chosen shortcuts for home or end. In my case, after using Powertoys as above:
Ctrl+Win+left takes the cursor to start of document, and
Ctrl+Win+right takes the cursor to end of document.

This works for me in Word and in R (everything I tested), where the start/end of document keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+home, Ctrl+end) seem to be installed by default.

If necessary you can install them in any program that allows you to customize keyboard shortcuts. In Word 2003 for example, this is under Tools > Customize > Keyboard (where the required shortcuts are present by default, but you can add to them if so desired).

One point for those new to PowerToys: Keyboard Manager must be enabled (with PowerToys running in the background) for remapped keys and shortcuts to be applied. You can set these to load at start-up.

Answer (score 0):

ON my brand new computer I made this same discovery and I used the HOME and END keys a lot to go to the beginning or end of a document.
I found that
ctrl + fn + arrow RIGHT key goes to the end
ctrl + fn + arrow LEFT key goes to the beginning

Answer (score 0):

This is partially working, but try pressing UP or DOWN arrow for your purpose. In most one-line text input fields, it does what HOME and END do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm excited to share my solution, which does not require you to install any software!  However, I would like to thank everyone here for their comments as it lead me to my solution.

I have an MK-Box keyboard from Amazon, which was made in China and has no documentation.  In general, I decided to observe all the Fn key combinations (i.e., Fn+key)

Step 1: Determine what key presses (scan codes) result from Fn key combinations.  I went [here](https://keyboardchecker.com/).

Step 2: Observe keys that registered until you find what you need (i.e., Home and End)

For me it ended up being the colon / semicolon (COLON) and single / double quote (QUOTE) keys.  Note, I am choosing the names COLON and QUOTE to make it clearer.  So, for Home I get Fn+COLON and End is Fn+QUOTE.

The keys were there all along, but I would never know without testing them as shown in Steps 1-2.

Answer (score -1):

MY NOTEBOOK = ASUS X202e

running W8:    Fn right arrow = END
               Fn  left arrow = HOME

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: The question explicitly says that the asker tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Simple friends . Our normal short cut to go 1st cell is Ctrl+home . In mini keyboards we have to add Fb key together as follows. CTRL+fn+home (left key).. the same as for end ( ctrl+fn+right key)

Comment: This duplicates MAC's answer.

Comment: Not simple at all. As my original question states, using the Fn button in combination with arrow keys does not work.